# If $a\lt0, b\ge0,$ what is the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^a\sin(x^b)?$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to determine the pairs $(a,b)$ for which $f(x)=x^a\sin(x^b)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$.
I know this is equivalent with the extendability of $f$ to a continuous function on $[0,1],$ thus I have to compute limits for various $a, b.$ And the only remaining case now, which is the case I am stuck at, is when $a\lt0, b\ge0.$
Thanks for any answer or reference in advance.

Comment: Depends on how $a$ and $b$ related. If $|a|>b$ it will blow up to infinity, if $|a|<b$ it will go to zero, and if $a=b$ then the limit is one.

Comment: Could you give me some hints on how to evaluate it? I am kind of driven crazy by the limit now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit you are looking at is the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x^b)}{x^{|a|}}$$
Rewrite it as
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (x^b)}{x^b}\cdot x^{b+a}.$$

The fraction obviously has a limit of $1$. If $a=-b$, the total limit is $1$, otherwise the factor of $x^{b+a}$ will cause the limit to go to $0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! The factoring-out is indeed amazing!

Comment: If the answer is useful, consider accepting it so the matter can be considered "closed".

Comment: OK. It is my pleasure. :P

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Taylor expansion of $sin(y)=y +...$; replace $y$ by $x^b$ and then you are looking for the limit of $x^{a+b}$ as shown by 5xum.

Comment: Of course this is valid, but I think there is no need of Taylor's expansion in such an "elementary" case. Still thanks. :)

Comment: @awllower. Don't you think that Taylor is invoked when writing that the limit of $sin(x)/x$ is $1$ when $x$ goes to zero ?

Comment: I mean: we can use the geometric proof, as expounded [Here.](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X#Geometric_Proof) I agree that the analytic definition of sine, or its Taylor expansion, indeed helps a lot, for me. :)